# Access denied when accessing /storage on android device with .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, android, maui

I am work with a Android application in .Net MAUI. Is simple aplication that goes access folders of images.
The problem is i am trying to configure the permissions to access the device image folders but whenever i go to read the folders in **/storage** i get the access denied message.
I'm not using an emulator. I'm compiling the project on a physical device.
Once the app is installed on the device and the exception is thrown, I check the app's permissions settings, and they are granted.

Another curious point is that when using "Android.OS.Environment.RootDirectory.Path" I manage to list all the folders and subfolders, but when I use "Android.OS.Environment.StorageDirectory.Path" which is what brings me /storage, the access denied exception happens.

What could be going wrong?

My Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

The Class permission request

```
public class RequestPermision
    {
        public static async Task RequestStoragePermissions()
        {
            if (DeviceInfo.Platform != DevicePlatform.Android)
                return;

            var status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;

            if (DeviceInfo.Version.Major >= 12)
            {
                status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<ReadWriteStoragePerms>();

                if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                    return;

                if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<ReadWriteStoragePerms>())
                {
                    await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Needs permissions", "BECAUSE!!!", "OK");
                }

                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() =>
                {
                    status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<ReadWriteStoragePerms>();
                });
            }
            else
            {
                status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();

                if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                    return;

                if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>())
                {
                    await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Needs permissions", "BECAUSE!!!", "OK");
                }

                status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();


            }

            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Permission required",
                            "Location permission is required for bluetooth scanning. " +
                            "We do not store or use your location at all.", "OK");
            });
            
            
        }
    }
```

```
public class ReadWriteStoragePerms : Permissions.BasePlatformPermission
    {
#if ANDROID
        public override (string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)[] RequiredPermissions =>
            new List<(string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)>
            {
                ("android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES", true),
                ("android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", true),
                ("android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", true),
                ("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", true)
            }.ToArray();
#endif
    }
```

The class that should list image folders

```
public class ListFolderAndroid
    {
        public static List<string> ListFolder()
        {
            var pictureFolders = new List<string>();

            // Obter o diretório principal de imagens do armazenamento externo
            var picturesDirectory = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);

            if (picturesDirectory != null && picturesDirectory.IsDirectory)
            {
                // Adicionar o caminho do diretório principal de imagens à lista
                pictureFolders.Add(picturesDirectory.Path);

                pictureFolders.AddRange(GetImageDirectories());
            }
            return pictureFolders;
        }

        public static List<string> GetImageDirectories()
        {
            List<string> directories = new List<string>();
            //string externalStorageDirectory = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStorageState(Android.OS.Environment.StorageDirectory);
            string externalStorageDirectory = Android.OS.Environment.StorageDirectory.Path;
            //string externalStorageDirectory = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStorageDirectory().AbsolutePath;
            TraverseDirectoriesForImages(new DirectoryInfo(externalStorageDirectory), directories);
            return directories;
        }

        private static void TraverseDirectoriesForImages(DirectoryInfo directory, List<string> imageDirectories)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var file in directory.GetFiles())
                {
                    if (IsImageFile(file))
                    {
                        string directoryPath = directory.FullName;
                        if (!imageDirectories.Contains(directoryPath))
                        {
                            imageDirectories.Add(directoryPath);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

                foreach (var subDirectory in directory.GetDirectories())
                {
                    TraverseDirectoriesForImages(subDirectory, imageDirectories);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static bool IsImageFile(FileInfo file)
        {
            string[] imageExtensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".bmp", ".gif" };
            return Array.IndexOf(imageExtensions, file.Extension.ToLower()) != -1;
        }


    }
```

Comment: There are Android APIs that allow you to access system media.  You don’t just directly read the data from filesyatem

Comment: No api should return a path like /storage. I dont believe it does. /storage/emulated/0 is possible.

Comment: You cannot access the entire filesystem directly, there are [APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i want to thank you for the tips.
They were very helpful in solving my problem.
I solving the problem in the following way.

I changed this code:

```
string externalStorageDirectory = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStorageState(Android.OS.Environment.StorageDirectory);
```

For this:

```
string externalStorageDirectory = Android.OS.Environment.StorageDirectory.Path + "/emulated/0";
```

Then when traversing the list of directories, I put a conditional to ignore all directories that start with "Android/".

```
foreach (var subDirectory in directory.GetDirectories())
{
   if(!subDirectory.ToString().Contains("Android/"))
     TraverseDirectoriesForImages(subDirectory, imageDirectories);
}
```

Everything works fine now.